# Create a dialog node that allows for document upload in Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I have created a chat-bot using IBM Watson Assistant and I am trying to find a way to allow the end user to upload documents through the Watson API. Has anyone else tried to achieve this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Watson service only takes text and then tries to classify and respond to it. Your application layer will have to either process this document into some form of a json string, or just collect it and do whatever else you want with it, and then send some kind of indicator to Watson to move on with the conversation.